# How to find invalid XML node in XDocument that is validated against a schema (XmlSchemaValidationException.SourceObject is null)

Tags: c#, validation, xsd, linq-to-xml

I have an `XDocument` that I validate against an XML schema. When the `XDocument` is invalid I need to find the invalid XML nodes so that the user can easily navigate to the respective place in my application (e.g. by double-clicking a message on a message grid).

I use the `System.Xml.Schema.Validate()` extension method for that purpose. The second argument of the Validate() method is a `System.Xml.ValidationEventHandler` which is called on every invalid XML element. It passes a `System.Xml.ValidationEventArgs`. The `ValidationEventArgs.Exception` can be casted to `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException`. Now the
`XmlSchemaValidationException` has a property `SourceObject` which I expected to hold a reference to the invalid XML node. Unfortunately it is always null.

The following snippet illustrates my usage:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\booksSchema.xml");

// Create the XmlSchemaSet class.
XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();

// Add the schema to the collection.
sc.Add("urn:bookstore-schema", @"c:\temp\books.xsd");

// Validate against schema
doc.Validate(sc, delegate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
                {
                    XmlSchemaValidationException ve = e.Exception as XmlSchemaValidationException;
                    if (ve != null)
                    {
                        object errorNode = ve.SourceObject;    
                        // ve.SourceObject is always null
                    }
                });
```

The validation itself works correctly, but I cannot get a reference on the invalid node. Strangely, the same approach works well for `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, but unfortunately I must work with `XDocument` in this context.

Does anyone have a suggestion how the invalid node can be found in `XDocument`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I have the answer. The invalid node is the event handler's "sender" itself. It can be cast to XContainer, XElement, ...